# PySpark SQL query to return row with most number of words

Tags: pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, where-clause

I am trying to come up with a pyspark sql query to return the row within the `text` column of the `review` Dataframe with the most number of words.

I would like to return both the full text as well as the number of words. This question is in regards to the reviews of the Yelp dataset. Here is what I have so far but apparently it is not (fully) correct:

```
query = """
SELECT text,LENGTH(text) - LENGTH(REPLACE(text,' ', '')) + 1 as count
    FROM review
    GROUP BY text
    ORDER BY count DESC
"""
spark.sql(query).show()
```

Here is an example of a few rows from the dataframe:

```
[Row(business_id='ujmEBvifdJM6h6RLv4wQIg', cool=0, date='2013-05-07 04:34:36', funny=1, review_id='Q1sbwvVQXV2734tPgoKj4Q', stars=1.0, text='Total bill for this horrible service? Over $8Gs. These crooks actually had the nerve to charge us $69 for 3 pills. I checked online the pills can be had for 19 cents EACH! Avoid Hospital ERs at all costs.', useful=6, user_id='hG7b0MtEbXx5QzbzE6C_VA'),
 Row(business_id='NZnhc2sEQy3RmzKTZnqtwQ', cool=0, date='2017-01-14 21:30:33', funny=0, review_id='GJXCdrto3ASJOqKeVWPi6Q', stars=5.0, text="I *adore* Travis at the Hard Rock's new Kelly Cardenas Salon!  I'm always a fan of a great blowout and no stranger to the chains that offer this service; however, Travis has taken the flawless blowout to a whole new level!  \n\nTravis's greets you with his perfectly green swoosh in his otherwise perfectly styled black hair and a Vegas-worthy rockstar outfit.  Next comes the most relaxing and incredible shampoo -- where you get a full head message that could cure even the very worst migraine in minutes --- and the scented shampoo room.  Travis has freakishly strong fingers (in a good way) and use the perfect amount of pressure.  That was superb!  Then starts the glorious blowout... where not one, not two, but THREE people were involved in doing the best round-brush action my hair has ever seen.  The team of stylists clearly gets along extremely well, as it's evident from the way they talk to and help one another that it's really genuine and not some corporate requirement.  It was so much fun to be there! \n\nNext Travis started with the flat iron.  The way he flipped his wrist to get volume all around without over-doing it and making me look like a Texas pagent girl was admirable.  It's also worth noting that he didn't fry my hair -- something that I've had happen before with less skilled stylists.  At the end of the blowout & style my hair was perfectly bouncey and looked terrific.  The only thing better?  That this awesome blowout lasted for days! \n\nTravis, I will see you every single time I'm out in Vegas.  You make me feel beauuuutiful!", useful=0, user_id='yXQM5uF2jS6es16SJzNHfg'),
 Row(business_id='WTqjgwHlXbSFevF32_DJVw', cool=0, date='2016-11-09 20:09:03', funny=0, review_id='2TzJjDVDEuAW6MR5Vuc1ug', stars=5.0, text="I have to say that this office really has it together, they are so organized and friendly!  Dr. J. Phillipp is a great dentist, very friendly and professional.  The dental assistants that helped in my procedure were amazing, Jewel and Bailey helped me to feel comfortable!  I don't have dental insurance, but they have this insurance through their office you can purchase for $80 something a year and this gave me 25% off all of my dental work, plus they helped me get signed up for care credit which I knew nothing about before this visit!  I highly recommend this office for the nice synergy the whole office has!", useful=3, user_id='n6-Gk65cPZL6Uz8qRm3NYw')]
```

And expected output if this was the review with the most words:

```
I have to say that this office really has it together, they are so organized and friendly!  Dr. J. Phillipp is a great dentist, very friendly and professional.  The dental assistants that helped in my procedure were amazing, Jewel and Bailey helped me to feel comfortable!  I don't have dental insurance, but they have this insurance through their office you can purchase for $80 something a year and this gave me 25% off all of my dental work, plus they helped me get signed up for care credit which I knew nothing about before this visit!  I highly recommend this office for the nice synergy the whole office has!
```

And then something like `Word count = xxxx`

Edit: Here the example output for the first review using this code:

```
query = """
SELECT text, size(split(text, ' ')) AS word_count 
    FROM review 
    ORDER BY word_count DESC
"""
spark.sql(query).show(20, False)
```

Review returned with highest number of words:

```
Got a date with de$tiny?
 
                          ** A ROMANTIC MOMENT WITH ** 
                            ** THE BEST VIEW IN TOWN**                                                 

                         ------------------------------------------------
                      /                   **CN TOWER'S**                  \ 
                     /         **REVOLVING RESTAURANT**     \         
                      \                                                                     /
                        \  ----------------------------------------------- /
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                               |                 |
                                             /                     \
                                            ===========

               o     o~
               /|~  ~|\
               /\     /  \        uhm, maybe not. the view may be great but a $30 to  
                                  $40 bleh $teak ain't necessarily gonna get you some
                                  action later. Cheaper to get takeout from Harvey's and 
                                  eat and the beach!                                                                                                        |4329      |
```

Comment: Typo. `GROUP BY` with space between the two words. However that's the least of your problem. It seems you haven't gave any thought to the logic behind your query

Comment: Got it! I made some edits.

Comment: Do provide us with an example dataframe with a couple of rows and an expected output to answer better. Otherwise from the text, looks like you don't need a group and only need to `order by count desc limit 1`

Comment: @snithish I made some more edits!

Comment: @Julien running your code does not generate all 1's but the expected output. 
`[Row(word_count='194'), Row(word_count='35'), Row(word_count='80')]
​`

Comment: I am still getting just 1's when I run it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulating the UDF you had into native SQL logic by splitting string into an array of words and finding the array size.

```
spark.sql("SELECT text, size(split(text, ' ')) as word_count FROM review ORDER BY word_count DESC").show(200, False)
```

## Example

```py
data = [("This is a sentence.",),  ("This sentence has 5 words.", )]

review = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("text", ))
review.registerTempTable("review")

spark.sql("SELECT text, size(split(text, ' ')) as word_count FROM review ORDER BY word_count DESC").show(200, False)
```

### Output

```
+--------------------------+----------+
|text                      |word_count|
+--------------------------+----------+
|This sentence has 5 words.|5         |
|This is a sentence.       |4         |
+--------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure that counts words and not characters?

Comment: Yes it does count the words.

Comment: Does it take into account ASCII characters? Some of the reviews have a bunch of them as drawings.

Comment: I tried `split('')` instead of `split(' ')` and that seems to work. All the reviews are 5000 words so that makes me think that's the Yelp word limit.

Comment: `split('')` would give you the character count and not the word count.

Comment: Well, shoot.....

Comment: I am still wondering about those ASCII characters though. I think with splitting by space it is counting the ASCII characters as words, so there are actually very few words in those reviews.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a small sample text for which the logic fails and then we can incrementally modify logic to fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239334/discussion-between-julien-and-snithish).